# Java Read Write Locks on a resource conserving memory

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, concurrenthashmap

In memory is a large collection of objects of type ***R***. To modify an object requires a write lock and to read requires a read lock. I could store a ReadWriteLock as a private member of the class ***R***, however, I want to conserve memory. At any time, only a small percentage of the objects are being modified or read.  There are various ways to decide to not store a read write lock for a particular resource (for example, if it has not be read or written to for some amount of time, *t*). For purposes of this question assume that periodically it can be determined that the lock for the resource can be deleted. However, keep in mind that while the  lock for the resource is being deleted in a thread, one or more other threads may attempt to modify or read the resource. All this is occuring in a multithreaded environment. How would you implement this with the least amount of locking?

For example, one way to do this is to store the read write locks in a concurrent map:

```java
Map<R,ReadWriteLock> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

When it is determined that the read write lock for a resource can be deleted then remove it from the map.  However, it may be possible as mentioned above that after it has been decided to delete the entry and before the entry is deleted, that other threads may want to acquire a read or write lock.

You may think that a combination of **computeifabsent** and **remove** can be used. However, that does not work. For example:

```
//--Thread1 write lock--
ReadWriteLock rwl = map.computeIfAbsent(r, r -> new ReadWriteLock()); // 1
rwl.writeLock.lock();                                        // 4
//Modify r here

//--Thread2: Removing entry--
map.remove(r);                                               // 2

//Thread3: write lock
ReadWriteLock rwl = map.computeIfAbsent(r, r-> new ReadWriteLock()); // 3
rwl.writeLock.lock();                                        // 5
//Modify r here.
```

The problem is that the lock object by thread 1 will not be the same as the lock obtained by thread 3 and incorrectly allowing two writes to occur at the same time. The numbers on the right show the order of execution.

An answer need not use a concurrent map as given in the example above but it seems to be a good start and provides concurrent access to locks. If you do use a concurrent map feel free to wrap the ReadWriteLock in another structure or to create your own version of ReadWriteLock.

In summary the question is how to maintain read write locks for a collection of resources without having to store a read write lock for every object in the collection and minimizing lock contention.

Comment: Is this homework or something similar? What is your actual question? It seems like an interesting problem, but I do not know what you are having trouble with.

Comment: before removing the `R` from the map, await the lock until it notifies.

Comment: @MalteHartwig No not homework. Basically how to maintain read write locks for a collection of objects without having to store a read write lock for every object.

Comment: @jaychang0917 ReadWriteLocks don't notify the lock and unlock.  Present some code if you think you have a solution.

Comment: Sorry, it is actually so well written that I thought it was. I think the question as is is too broad, maybe you could show your effort and point out what is not working specifically.

Comment: @MalteHartwig Well I was a computer science professor at one time :)  I added a summary of the question at the end. Also I have already shown some of my effort in the code above; use concurrenthashmap and putifabsent, remove combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the methods `compute` and `computeIfPresent` to your advantage. The important thing is to do the adding/locking/removing **inside** the consumers to have it done atomically.

*Note: you used `putIfAbsent` in your example, but that returns the **previously** asigned value, not the **newly** assigned value.*

```
public static class Locks<R>
{
    private ConcurrentHashMap<R, ReentrantReadWriteLock> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void lock(R r, Function<ReentrantReadWriteLock, Lock> whichLock)
    {
        locks.compute(r, (key, lock) -> {
            ReentrantReadWriteLock actualLock = lock == null ? new ReentrantReadWriteLock() : lock;
            whichLock.apply(actualLock).lock();
            return actualLock;
        });
    }

    public void unlock(R r, Function<ReentrantReadWriteLock, Lock> whichLock)
    {
        locks.computeIfPresent(r, (key, lock) -> {
            whichLock.apply(lock).unlock();
            return lock; // you could return null here if lock is unlocked (see cleanUp) to remove it immediately
        });
    }

    public void cleanUp()
    {
        for (R r : new ArrayList<>(locks.keySet()))
        {
            locks.computeIfPresent(r, (key, lock) -> locks.get(r).isWriteLocked()
                                                     || locks.get(r).getReadLockCount() != 0 ? lock : null);
        }
    }
}
```

Note how I use

- `compute` in `lock` to create new locks and lock them immediately
- `computeIfPresent` in `unlock` to check whether there is a lock at all
- `computeIfPresent` in `cleanUp` to check whether a lock is needed without another thread locking write lock while I am checking read lock count

Right now, `unlock` is rather useless (except for null checks, which is just a precaution). Returning `null` in `unlock` would nicely clean up unnecessary locks and make `cleanUp` obsolete, but might increase the need for new locks being created. This depends on how frequently locks are used.

You could add convenience methods for read/write, of course, instead of having to provide the getter `whichLock`.

Comment: This looks really good.  I did fix the issue with putifabsent in my code.

Comment: Why are you saying unlock is rather useless?

Comment: The java documentation says not to use isWriteLocked and getReadLockCount for synchronization control (perhaps not what is being done here), but this seems like a great use of those methods.

Comment: This solution has a trivial deadlock when two threads attempt to get the same write lock. The first thread creates/gets the lock. Then the second thread tries to get the same write lock and blocks the CHM compute method on Lock#lock which blocks the first thread's unlock method.

Comment: @JohnH you are absolutely right. Should have known that it's not as simple. Have to come back to it later.

Comment: I don't think the unlock method is necessary. Instead have the lock methods return the lock and have caller unlock the locks.  See my suggested edits above.  @MalteHartwig if you agree can you fix the code above?

Comment: @MalteHartwig By the way for cleanup there is no guarantee that there may not be other calls to read or write while the cleanup methods is called. But that is OK. There may be better ways to determine when to attempt cleanup

Answer (score 1):

> the question is how to maintain read write locks for a collection of resources without having to store a read write lock for every object in the collection and minimizing lock contention

Have you considered using striped locks? (e.g., https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html)

Basically, it's a collection of N locks for M data where N < M. A hash function is used to map the identity of any given datum to the lock that controls it.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, however, it has several shortcomings. Mainly I think it would cause too much blocking. There is a better solution presented by @MalteHartwig

Comment: Looking at this further, this may be a better answer.  I guess I would use a weak lock?